# Can't get cloned disk online despite changing it's uniqueid via diskpart?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, diskpart, disk-management, disk-cloning

I've cloned a data drive using a StarTech disk duplicator, and now would like to view both drives simultaneously in Windows.

Disk Management throws up a "Offline (The disk is offline because it has a signature collision with another disk that is online)" error.

I'm wary to simply click "Online" on that disk as it's unclear to me what that does - could it cause problems?

Instead I did some googling and found many references to this problem, with everyone suggesting this sequence of events:

- run diskpart
- select disk x
- uniqueid disk ID=#NEWID#

I created a new ID by adding 1 to each segment, so 4FEEE371-7836-4E05-9C1A-CB7A1199A3BD became 4FEEE372-7837-4E06-9C1B-CB7A1199A3BE.  (At first I tried just changing the very last digit but that didn't seem to be good enough).

I feel by changing each segment Windows must surely now see that as a new uniqueid, but I still get the same error message, even after removing/reconnecting the drive and after a reboot.

Is there something else I should be changing as well as the uniqueid?

Thanks

Comment: Can you mount both the disks (original and cloned) under another OS? Try with a Linux version on pen-drive. If you can do it the problem may depends on some of the information written on the disk by the Microsoft System (I mean it can be written inside some file or position somewhere on the cloned disk that that partition is associated on the old ID and the system may go to read there instead of the real ID...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to be afraid of clicking "Online" on that disk.

This will force Disk Management to generate a new disk signature for the offline
disk, which is much safer than using `diskpart` and more effective.
Your data should not be affected.

Comment: I've just tried it. The disk came online, but the signature remained the same as while it was offline.